# jQuery form submitting isn't submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a basic HTML form which I validate through jQuery,

this is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="add_product">
    מק"ט:
    <input type="text" name = "product_cn" value="<?php echo $product_cn;?>" id="cn"/> <span style="margin-right: 20px; color:red; display:none" id="cn_exist"></span>
    <br /> <br />
    שם המוצר:
    <input type="text" name="product_name" value="<?php echo $product_name;?>" id="p_name"/>
    <br /> <br />
    פרטי המוצר:
    <textarea rows = "6" cols = "30" name="product_details"  id="p_details"> <?php echo $product_details;?></textarea>
    <br /> <br />
    מחיר:
    <input type="text" name = "product_price" value="<?php echo $product_price;?>" id="p_price"/>
    <br /> <br />

    תמונה:
    <input type="file" name="fileField" id="p_image" />
    <br /> <br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="רשום מוצר"  />
</form>
```

this is my validation code:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(e);
            var p_cn = $("#cn").val();
            var p_name = $("#p_name").val();
            var p_details = $("#p_details").val();
            var p_price = $("#p_price").val();
            var p_image = $("#p_image").val();

            error = "";
            if(!(p_cn != "") || !(p_cn.length > 0)){
                error += " אנא הוסף הוסף מק\"ט <br /> <br />" ;
            }
            if(!(p_name != "") || !(p_name.length > 0)){
                error += "אנא הזן שם מוצר <br /> <br />";
            }

            if(!(p_price != "") || !(p_name.length > 0)){
                error += " אנא הזמן מחיר. <br /> <br />";
            }


            if(error != ""){
                $("#form_errors").html(error).hide().slideDown(500);
            }else{
                $("#form_errors").slideUp(500);
                $("#add_product").submit();
            }

        });
```

Please ignore any character you don't understand, it's my language.

As you can see, what I did is prevent the form from being submitted, I had to use the selector "form" or otherwise, it just won't work for some reason >_<. Therefore, I tried using the selector "form" and it worked.

Now, as you can see in the last IF condition, I want to submit the form if the variable "error" is empty, but the form just doesnt submit. I would like to know how to make the form submit :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first line of your submit function is: `e.preventDefault(e);`, which prevents the default action of the form, which prevents the form from being submitted.

Comment: thanks mate, the first answer explained what you tried to say ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `e.preventDefault()` is to stop the element's default action. In a form.submit(), it prevents the form from being submitted.

[Here is a detailed explanation](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/)

Move the preventDefault() to here:

```
if(error != ""){
    $("#form_errors").html(error).hide().slideDown(500);
    e.preventDefault(); //do NOT want it to submit if there are errors
}else{
    $("#form_errors").slideUp(500);
    $("#add_product").submit();
}
```

Comment: The guy above you said the same :) thanks anyways! one question, why when I do `$("#add_product").submit(function() { etc.});` it isn't working? why do I have to use the "form" selector?

Comment: Not sure about that, but did you get a chance to glance at the article I linked (from css-tricks). I found it very helpful for understanding both `preventDefault` and `return false`, which is really what your question is about. I created this answer and expanded on my initial comment so that I could post that, and point out exactly where the preventDefault should go.

Answer (score 2):

`e.preventDefault(e);` (which should be just `e.preventDefault();`) stops the submit from happening. You need to do that conditionally:

```
if (error) {
    e.preventDefault();
} else {
    // No need to prevent the submit
}
```

Comment: nice one :) didn't think about the TBH :-)
One more question, why when I do `$("#add_product").submit(function() { etc.});`

it isn't working? why do I have to use the "form" selector?